# Land line control using PC

Tags: linux, windows, phone

I wish to control my land line from my PC.

NOTE: I do *not* mean having a SIP client in my PC. Rather, I want to:

1. control ON/OFF HOOK
2. bring voice into the PC so that it can be processed using voice recognition software
3. send voice out to the landline, either pre-recorded or synthetically generated
4. dial outward bound calls
5. be notified of incoming calls
6. be able to recognize various call progress states (ringing, busy, fast-busy, call disconnect)

Comment: http://lifehacker.com/400530/build-your-own-pbx-with-asterisk enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

High end modems used to have this functionality 20 years ago.  However, you will be hard pressed to find it now.  Modems are rare these days and the only ones I have seen are bare bones.  You might be able to find some if you look around and get lucky.  Perhaps there are some older modems that are still being sold?